# Writing grok filter for my use case

Tags: logstash-grok

I have the following log file,

**[2017-07-07 11:41:30.794][DEBUG][Hello]**

for the above log, i have written the grok filter as shown below,
match => {"message" =>"[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:TimeStamp}][%{LOGLEVEL:logLevel}][%{WORD:machineName}]"}

But i have another scenario where my last part of the log is little changed as below,

**[2017-07-07 11:41:30.794][DEBUG][C:0:O:1]**

For this i am not able to write the proper grok filter. I tried the below,

match => {"message" =>"[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:TimeStamp}][%{LOGLEVEL:logLevel}][%{HOSTNAME:machineName}]"}

HOSTNAME is not working. Can you please suggest which keyword to use.

Comment: Both of your grokstrings simply won't work because you do not escape your brackets. If you wan't to match your machineName just use a `GREEDYDATA`

Comment: There are some other patterns after machine name.. I just mentioned some part of it.. What is the exact keyword for **C:0:O:1**

Comment: @Fairy  I am skipping the brackets.. But when i paste here, i dont know its not showing. Its strange. But my logstash filter syntax is correct.. Not to worry about that

Answer (score 0):

Vinod , you might want to try skipping the [, ] brackets with \ like

```
\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:TimeStamp}\]\[%{LOGLEVEL:logLevel}\]\[%{HOSTNAME:machineName}\]
```

It should work

Nikhil

Comment: If my input is C:0:O:1, then HOSTNAME:machineName is not able to parse it.
But if my input is C:0:O.1, then HOSTNAME:machineName is able to parse it.

Is it because there is : already present in HOSTNAME:machineName… how to solve it. Please help me here

Answer (score 0):

Also , if you getting something like [C:0:O:1] , then you can identify with

```
\[%{GREEDYDATA:machineName}\]
```

But if you can provide more log line samples, that would help to suggest the correct pattern

Nikhil

Comment: i cant use greedy data as i have other fields after machine name. I will paste my complete filter here,     **match => {"message" =>"\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:TimeStamp}\]\[%{LOGLEVEL:logLevel}\]\[%{HOSTNAME:machineName}\]\[%{JAVACLASS:className}\]                  \[%{JAVAMETHOD:methodName}\]\[%{WORD:commandID}\]                  \[%{GREEDYDATA:myMessage}\]"}**

Comment: For machineName, if i give C:0:O:1, it doesnt work. But if i give C-0-O-1, it works..  But i want to know the proper keyword which can parse C:0:O:1.

Comment: I am skipping the brackets.. But when i paste here, i dont know its not showing. Its strange. But my logstash filter syntax is correct.. Not to worry about that